# Encrypt FIle in Node.JS without IV

Tags: node.js, encryption, hash, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a file using crypto module in Node.js before uploading it to IPFS. I want to have the same result every time I encrypt the same file so I computed the hash of the file using crypto.createHash().

For encrypting the file, right now I'm using the crypto.createCipheriv(). I wanted to know if there are other ways to encrypt a file without the iv? I wanted to just use the hash I computed to encrypt the file to ensure that I get the same result every time.

I'm using Node.js v16.14.0

Comment: A ciphertext that changes for each encryption is a security feature. So you ask for a way to make your encryption more insecure. The ECB mode does not use an IV and thus generates the same ciphertext for each encryption. Technically what you want, but not recommendable since inherently insecure, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946/94390).